# Group items from database table and calculate total price for each item given a number of items

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sum, grouping

I have a multidimensional array. I need to group and sum the values of the array that have the same index name. Here is what I have:

```
Array
(
[Garlic Potatoes] => 625
[Rice] => 1025
[Chicken Shawarma] => 1675
[Pita Bread Sm] => 6
[Pita Bread Large] => 14
[Beef Shawarma] => 1755
[Can of Pop] => 2
[Brioch Bun] => 2
[Chicekn Shawarama] => 135
)
```

How can I end up with one instance of Chicken Shawarma and qty = 1405 ? Do I need to use a foreach?

```
$sql = "SELECT menu_id, SUM(quantity) AS qty FROM daily_consumption_details WHERE consumption_id = $id GROUP BY menu_id";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

$ingredients = [];

while($menu = $res->fetch_object())
{

    $sql_ing = "SELECT item_name, quantity FROM menu_details WHERE menu_id = $menu->menu_id ";
    $rs = $conn->query($sql_ing);
    while($items = $rs->fetch_object())
    {
        $qty = $menu->qty * $items->quantity;
    
        if ( array_key_exists(trim($items->item_name), $ingredients) ) 
            $ingredients[trim($items->item_name)] = $qty + $ingredients[trim($items->item_name)];
        else 
            $ingredients[trim($items->item_name)] = $qty; 

    }
}
```

Comment: This whole php process should be replaced with a single trip to the database (a single SQL query).

Comment: This looks topical: [MySQL: Calculating total price for each order in a restaurant database by multiplying the price and quantity columns located in two separate tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64638411/2943403)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you make the `item_name` the key of the new ingredients array you can easily check if you already created an entry for this ingredient

```
while($menu = $res->fetch_object())
{

    $sql_ing = "SELECT item_name, quantity FROM menu_details WHERE menu_id = $menu->menu_id ";
    $rs = $conn->query($sql_ing);
    while($items = $rs->fetch_object())
    {
        $qty = $menu->qty * $items->quantity;
        $item = trim($items->item_name);
        if ( array_key_exists($item, $ingredients) ) {
            $ingredients[$items] += $qty;
        } else {
            $ingredients[$items] = $qty; 
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting `$ingredients` array will look about the same except the key will be the item name and not a numeric, 0,1,2, etc

Comment: Thank you! I updated the code and the output. Also adjusted the code since if the index is the item name then no need for item. It appears it isn't updating instead it creates a new one

Comment: Spaces are relevant, one has a space prefix and the other a space suffix, so lets trim the string before using it

Comment: Thank you! Just did that, trim worked! I was not expecting spaces. That was bad data input.